# What's the command to go to previous word's end in vim?

Tags: vim

In gvim, since button e is the command to go to next word's end, then what's the command to go to previous word's end? I tried Shift+e, but it seems it works the same as single e.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command to go to the end of the previous word is `ge`. See

```
:help word-motions
```

for a list of these commands.

Comment: Exactly what I want, nice.